What is a good python data structure for storing instances of different types of data?
I am working on a program in python to record data of different types. I'm thinking of a hierarchical data structure like below:
                                    dataStructure
                              /                      \
                     dataType1                          dataType2
                /        |        \                /        |        \
           instance1 instance2 instance3      instance1 instance2 instance3

I need to be able to create new instances of each type of data and new dataTypes in runtime. Each instance of every data type would follow the same pattern with a time, type and data. I'm just not sure how exactly to make this workable in runtime.
When getting a new instance of data, the program shoud see if it matches a dataType already in the structure, if not, create a new dataType in the dataStructure and insert the instance into that dataType
I tried nested dictionaries but that became extremely clumsy quickly and I couldn't keep track of where things were going. Maybe nested dictionaries is the right choice but I'm not going about it the right way.

Suppose dataType2 is a subclass of dataType1, should it have its own list of instances (that's easier).

I don't understand why a simple dictionary won't work.  {dataType1: [instance1, instance2], dataType2: [instance1], ...}

@JohnGordon So to access a data in instance1 it would be structure['dataType1'][0]['data'] right? I didn't think of dictionary of lists.

What is the meaning of a parent-child relationship in your tree? Why a tree at all?

After reading the comments on my initial question, I was able to develop a data structure that works well for me.
Calling the function add_data_instance with a dictionary checks to see if the 'name' already exists as a key in the main data structure, if it does, it appends the dictionary in the list under that key, if not, it creates the key, then appends the instance dictionary
data_structure = {}

def add_data_instance(new_data):
    if (new_data['name'] in data_structure):
        data_structure[new_data['name']].append(new_data)
    else:
        data_structure[new_data['name']] = []
        data_structure[new_data['name']].append(new_data)


add_data_instance({'name': 'data1', 'time':'today','data':'6usfon457jfdsgj'})

print(data_structure['data1'][0]['data']) #returns '6usfon457jfdsgj'

The main dictionary allows me to collate instances of data based on their names and the list allows for very easy iteration through the instances under a certain key.

This is a significant update from the question. It appears that data_structure is a mapping object like a dict and you want lists indexed by its "name" value.

You can use collections.defaultdict. It will automatically create new key/value pairs when a new key is seen. It's the same thing as your answer but using the standard lib.
import collections
data_structure = collections.defaultdict(list)
test1 = {'name': 'data1', 'time':'today','data':'6usfon457jfdsgj'}
data_structure[test1['name']].append(test1)
print(data_structure['data1'][0]['data'])


I didn't know the collections library existed, I'll look into it. Thanks!

A good Python data structure for storing instances of different types of data, especially when new instances and data types need to be created dynamically, is to use a combination of dictionaries and lists. Here's a suggestion on how you could structure your data:
You can use a dictionary where the keys represent the data types, and the values are lists of instances for that particular data type. Each instance can be represented as a dictionary with keys for time, type and data.
Here's a simple example to illustrate this structure:
data_structure = {}

# Function to add a new instance to the data structure
def add_instance(data_type, time, data):
    if data_type no in data_structure:
        data_structure[data_type] = []
    
    new_instance = {
        "time": time,
        "type": data_type,
        "data": data
    }

    data_structure[data_type].append(new_instance)

# Example of adding instances
add_instance("dataType1", "2024-04-23 12:00:00", {"value": 42})
add_instance("dataType2", "2024-04-23 12:15:00", {"name": "Alice"})

# Printing the data structure
print(data_structure)

